# File shows up in ls but cannot rm or mv, seems to be held by some unknown process

Tags: linux

I do a lot of work on an SGE cluster running CentOS 7, and have recently had issues with jobs dying randomly, but seemingly with some processes still running that prevent me from cleaning up to start over. When I try to delete the necessary files, I get a "no such file or directory" message, yet the file shows up in ls.  Forum searches told me this could be because of non-printing characters in the name, but I can't create a file with the same name using touch, or remove it with rm -i. E.g:

```
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ rm file_bad.csv 
rm: cannot remove ‘file_bad.csv’: No such file or directory
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ rm -f file_bad.csv 
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ ls file*
file1.csv  file2.csv  file_bad.csv
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ touch file_bad.csv 
touch: cannot touch ‘file_bad.csv’: No such file or directory
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ rm -i -- file_bad.csv 
rm: cannot remove ‘file_bad.csv’: No such file or directory
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ ls file*
file1.csv  file2.csv  file_bad.csv
```

As such I'm fairly certain the issue is that the bad file is being held by some process, and when I brought it up with the cluster admins the only solution they came up with was giving them the file name so that they could delete it.  This has been happening too frequently for that to be a sustainable solution, so I wanted to ask here if there is anything else I can do to solve the problem myself, like to somehow force delete the file and close all processes that are getting in the way?

Most of the time I don't know which cluster node the suspected process is running on, and I don't know of a way to somehow check all of them to find and kill the appropriate process… If I run the lsof command from the node I'm logged into, it never turns up anything.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There are most likely invisible bad characters in the name. ls -b, -Q, --quoting-style=shell or --quoting-style=shell-always

Comment: Thanks for your response @bmargulies, but I don't think that's it: ls -Q output is identical to ls except with quotes (no spaces revealed).  Also "touch file_bad.csv" returns an error, which it shouldn't if file_bad.csv was not the complete name, right?

Comment: Do an `ls -i` to see the inode numbers of each file.  Then use `find . -inum NUMBER -print` to confirm, then delete the file with `find . -inum NUMBER -delete` or `find . -inum NUMBER -exec rm -f {} \; -print` if the -delete option is not available.  If that still does not work, use `fuser` on the file to see what process has it.  Worst case, restart system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Nic3500. Frustratingly I get the same behavior using `find . -inum NUMBER`: with `-delete` it says "no such file or directory", but it shows up with `-print`.  Similarly, `fuser` says the file does not exist. Also, I should've emphasized in my post that the system is a remote cluster where I'm not an admin, so restarting is not an option.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @jww.  I actually meant to post this in Unix & Linux but somehow went back to the wrong tab on my browser or something without noticing.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

> lsof /absolute/path/to/file_bad.csv

If the above command yields any output you will find the PID responsiblr for keeping that file in use.

You could also try the below cmd to remove the file.

> find /path/to/file -type f -name 'file_bad.csv' -exec rm -f {} \;

Comment: With this I get `lsof: status error on /absolute/path/to/file_bad.csv: No such file or directory`.  The `find` command doesn't through an error, but the file is still there.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the filename is composed of special characters that you do not see in your terminal. Please try: "find /path/to/file -type f -name '*ile*'" and let me know what it finds

Comment: Edit: -name "<star widlcard>ile<star widlcard>"  . I can't type * in the comment it seems